# error while installing luagraph

Tags: lua, luarocks

```
Installing http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/luagraph-1.0.4-1.src.rock...
Using http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/luagraph-1.0.4-1.src.rock... switching to 'build' mode
Archive:  /tmp/luarocks_luarocks-rock-luagraph-1.0.4-1-656/luagraph-1.0.4-1.src.rock
  inflating: luagraph-1.0.4-1.rockspec  
  inflating: luagraph-1.0.4.tar.gz   

Error: Could not find expected file graphviz/graph.h for GRAPHVIZ -- you may have to install GRAPHVIZ in your system and/or pass GRAPHVIZ_DIR or GRAPHVIZ_INCDIR to the luarocks command. Example: luarocks install luagraph GRAPHVIZ_DIR=/usr/local
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error mentions, "*you may have to install GRAPHVIZ in your system*". TO do so, follow the instructions available on their download support page: http://www.graphviz.org/Download..php